# How to include images into jsp with spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I can't display my image into a jsp page.

[my webapp structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OTSS.png)

**My configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.gruppoaton")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

**My Header**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head style:background-color:>

<style>
    div{
        background-color: #0066ff;
    }
</style>
<div></div>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<img align="left" src="<c:url value="/logoAtonBianco.png"/>" alt=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched for hours on this site, and it looks like i did everything done, but it still don't working and can't display anything. Any advice?

Comment: you probably tried `/images/logoAtonBianco.png` ?

Comment: Same! Nothing display

Comment: I think you may need to find the file relative to where your jsp is located, like `../images/logoAtonBianco.png`. try that.

Comment: I tried to put the image into the same path of the jsp page and ita worked.
Now, i want to put the logo into the **images** folder, what i have to change for that?

Comment: see my previous comment. `../` you need to step back and then into /images/ because images folder is on the same level as the jsp.

Comment: It worked! Thx a lot!

Comment: great! glad to help